# Problems to parse structured JSON-LD file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, semantic-web, json-ld

I try to parse a JSON-LD file with Nodejs using the [jsonld-streaming-parser.js](https://github.com/rubensworks/jsonld-streaming-parser.js) library.

The file is a structured JSON-LD so all the elements I'm interested in are located at the root of the `@graph`:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/ontology/core#",
    "schema": "http://schema.org/",
    "bd": "http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#",
    (...)
  },
  "@graph": [{
    "@id": "https://data.datatourisme.gouv.fr/3/06a7f439-3e02-3aa2-8301-f850bb5b792f",
    "dc:date": [{
      "@value": "2013-10-30",
      "@type": "xsd:date"
    },{
      "@value": "2019-08-30",
      "@type": "xsd:date"
    }],
    "dc:identifier": "eudonet:52945",
    "@type": ["schema:Landform","NaturalHeritage","PlaceOfInterest","PointOfInterest","urn:resource"],
    "rdfs:label": {
      "@value": "L'arbre du Pied Cornier",
      "@language": "fr"
    },
    (...)
  }]
}
```

I can parse the file using the following code:

```
const JsonLdParser = require('jsonld-streaming-parser').JsonLdParser;

const parser = new JsonLdParser();

const getStream = () => {
  const jsonData = 'flux-5339-201909240851.partial.jsonld';
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(jsonData, {encoding: 'utf8'});
  return stream.pipe(parser);
};

getStream()
  .on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('data = ', data);
  })
  .on('error', () => {
    console.error(error);
  })
  .on('end', () => {
    console.log('All triples were parsed!');
  });
```

I expect to have the comprehensive content for an element within the `data` callback but got this:

```
{
  "subject": {
    "value": "https://data.datatourisme.gouv.fr/3/06a7f439-3e02-3aa2-8301-f850bb5b792f"
  },
  "predicate": {
    "value": "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/date"
  },
  "object": {
    "value": "2013-10-30",
    "datatype": {
      "value": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date"
    },
   "language": ""
  },
  "graph": {
    "value": ""
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help!
Thierry

Comment: What do you mean by `comprehensive content`?

Comment: I mean all the fields I have in the file for elements. For example: label, types, dates, ... Thanks for your message!

Answer (score 0):

The JsonLd Streaming parser library you're using appears to only transform JsonLd into RDF triples (see [RDF spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#section-triples) for details).

I think what you want from your description is a [frame](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld11-framing/#dfn-framing) of the JsonLd graph. You can achieve that using the standard [JsonLd parsing library for Node](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/jsonld.js/).

In your case the frame should be as simple as

```
{
    "@context": {
        "@vocab": "https://www.datatourisme.gouv.fr/ontology/core#",
        "schema": "http://schema.org/",
        "bd": "http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#",
        (...)
     },
     "@id": "https://data.datatourisme.gouv.fr/3/06a7f439-3e02-3aa2-8301-f850bb5b792f"
}
```

which should give you the attributes for the first item in compact JsonLd. If you have multiple items in the graph you can change the `@id` to `@type` and return all items which match a particular type.